# alignment changes when button is clicked

Tags: button, text, alignment

I am facing the problem of alignment when a button is clicked. Before the button is clicked, when expanding(using + icon) for the info, the content is properly aligned. But after the button is clicked and then it is expanded for the information, the alignment is changed. Note: No relation to the button and expansion. I inspected with firebug. All the margins and paddings, floats are the same for the info content before and after clicking the button.

Thanks

Comment: What type of alignment do you have on the button?(left,center,right) Is there a focus/highlight which appears after the button is clicked?

Comment: the button is floated right and it is enclosed in a td tag of table. Once button is clicked, it changes to a text inside the same td only.